# Facebook App Tester - do they have to be a developer?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-app-requests

I just added a couple of friends as "testers" for my app. I can assign administrators, developers, testers and analyticers and according to

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/security

only admins and developers must have a developer account (at least facebook mentions this requirement only for these two roles).

So, all my friends have a "pending" next to them in my roles-overview and they say that do get a notification saying I invited them, but cannot accept without becoming a developer.

Did I make a mistake, or did facebook just forget to list this requirement on their roles-page?

Would appreciate any clarification. Thanks :)

Comment: i believe it´s new. maybe they did not update their docs yet.

Comment: Thanks luschn. I just got the confirmation in facebook developer group. Yes, they changed it recently. Doesn't make sense to me at all but I'm afraid there is nothing you can do about it.